# Fazer 1 figura com 3 gráficos

Tags: python, python-2.7

Tenho 3 funções como as seguintes que permite obter cada uma um gráfico e pretendo uma função em que use os 3 gráficos das outras funções para juntar numa só figura.

```
def funcao1(grafico):
    ...
    pylab.plot(range(len(x)), y)
    pylab.xticks(z,sorted(set(x)))
    pylab.title("crimes")
    pylab.xlabel("Anos")
    pylab.ylabel("# Crimes")
    pylab.show()

def funcao2(grafico):
    ...
    pylab.plot(range(len(y)), x)
    pylab.xticks(b,sorted(set(y)))
    pylab.title("nomes")
    pylab.xlabel("Anos")
    pylab.ylabel("# Crimes")
    pylab.show()

def funcao3(grafico):
    ...
    pylab.plot(range(len(a)), e)
    pylab.xticks(p,sorted(set(a)))
    pylab.title("idades")
    pylab.xlabel("Anos")
    pylab.ylabel("# Crimes")
    pylab.show()

def quatro_figuras(grafico):

      #Aqui obter uma figura com os 3 graficos
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que deves usar o comando subplot, se não me engano o código deverá ficar desta forma:

```
y = [1,2,3]
x = [5,6,7]

def funcao1(): 
    pylab.subplot(221)
    pylab.title("crimes")
    pylab.xlabel("Anos")
    pylab.ylabel("# Crimes")
    pylab.plot(range(len(x)), y)

def funcao2():
    pylab.subplot(222)
    pylab.title("nomes")
    pylab.xlabel("Anos")
    pylab.ylabel("# Crimes")
    pylab.plot(range(len(x)), y)

def funcao3():
    pylab.subplot(223)
    pylab.title("idades")
    pylab.xlabel("Anos")
    pylab.ylabel("# Crimes")
    pylab.plot(range(len(x)), y)

def quatro_figuras():
    pylab.show()

funcao1()
funcao2()
funcao3()
quatro_figuras()
```

Sendo que o 1º algarismo corresponde ao número de linhas de gráficos, o 2º o número de colunas e o 3º corresponde ao número de cada gráfico.
Um exemplo pode ser visto [aqui](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html#working-with-multiple-figures-and-axes).

Altera o exemplo de acordo com o teu trabalho.

Comment: Não está a dar correto , quando o faço ele faz " none "

Comment: @user44708 em que linha?

Comment: Por exemplo quando corro a funçao " quatro_figuras" com F5  , aparece " None " , não faz nada

Comment: @user44708 antes de correr essa função evocas-te as funções 1, 2 e 3?

Comment: É isso mesmo , obrigado :)